# "word-break: break-word" does not get reflected in the image created by html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas for downloading  the html view as an image.

However, if there is a long text without spaces, the html renders it properly on the next line using css (word-break: break-word) but this does not reflect in the image that is generated. The text stays in one line and gets clipped.

tried other CSS properties like:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

still did not work

check below image for expected vs actual result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfuVT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add **letterRendering:true** property in html2canvas method.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById(divId), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        },
    letterRendering:true
});
```

Comment: I added letterRendering: true 
Not working for me :-(

Comment: This does not work anymore after version v0.4.1 (`letterRendering` is not present on the [reference](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration))... Any updated solutions?

Comment: Update: @ShashikantKanaujiya's syntax was wrong: use `word-break: break-all` instead

Answer (score 0):

For the people like me who needed the `word-break: break-word;` and not `word-break: break-all;` adding `overflow-wrap: break-word;` In addition to what Dhananjay Chaudhari said seems to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).